# Sqlite connection string in web.config

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, iis-7

I have published my web project to local iis but framework can't find the "db" file. In debugging there is no problem, i can connect but in localhost i can't. Here is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PROD" connectionString="data source=app.db;" providerName="System.Data.SQLite"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

I tried everything "../app.db" "direct_path" "~/app.db"

What might the problem?

---

It can find the database in D:\ drive or other than inetpub drive. I didn't understand if it's a permission problem or not. How can i find the exact solution for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i got the physical path with System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory and then find the path of sqlite file. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

this is most likely a permissions issue. this works while debugging because the website is running under your credentials and you have full control. when deployed it's running under IIS_USRS which is highly restrictive and, most likely, doesn't have write permissions to the file by default.

provide the IIS_USRS account with read/write permissions to the directory/file and this should work.

Comment: i gave all the permissions to file / folder but no hope.

Comment: data source = |DataDirectory|app.db is my connection string App_Data directory is under bin dir when i publish the project